# Why do I not get any results from MongoOperation when querying for an entity?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

When I execute request to db

```
db.users.find({"name": "Max"})
```

I get this result

```
{"_id":ObjectId("5785718ee271a7c7ebaad28b"),"name":"Max","visits-by-day":[{"day":"Thursday","visitsAmount":20},{"day":"Saturday","visitsAmount":4}]}
```

JSON structure example:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "Bobby",
      "visits-by-day": [
        {
          "day": "Sunday",
          "visitsAmount": 8
        },
        {
          "day": "Monday",
          "visitsAmount": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here my Java code

```
MongoUser user = mongoTemplate.findOne(query(where("name").is("Max")), MongoUser.class);
```

The model

```
@Document
public class MongoUser {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<VisitsPerDay> visitsByDay;
    // Getters & Setters omitted
}

public class VisitsPerDay {
    private String day;
    private Integer visitsAmount;
    // Getters & Setters omitted
}
```

Why Spring does return a null empty instead of serialized Java object?

Comment: Is it just a typo that you search for "Max" in the first query and for "Moshe" in the MongoTemplate query?

Comment: It's a typo in question.

Comment: @Mark You forgot to add `@Document(collection = "users")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the collection queried for a given typed is derived from the simple name of the domain type you want to read. In your case, that would be `mongoUser`. To get your example to work, you basically have two options:

1. Explicitly configure the `collectionName` in the `@Document` annotation on `MongoUser` to `users`. That will basically tie instances of that class to that collection and let all data access operations for that class to work with that collection (e.g. for repositories etc.).
2. When calling `MongoTemplate`, use the overload of `findOne(…)` that takes an explicit collection name:

   ```
   template.findOne(query(…), MongoUser.class, "users");
   ```